# How to check if I have some error in my hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I try to check if I have an error in my token, 
In my view it works like this and it seems to be Ok :

```
<% if @token['error'].present?%>
    <%= @token['error']%> // display the message of the error
    <%= flash[:error]%> //display ERROR
    <% else %>
    <%= @token%> // display the token
    <p>Ok</p>
<%end%>
```

But in my controller, I can't do that :

```
 if @token['error'].present?
            flash[:error] = "ERROR"
        else
            @token = HTTParty.post('https://mooncard23-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/auth/token/access', 
                body: {
                    client_id: XXXXXXXXXX,
                    client_secret: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
                    code: @decoded_code
                }
            ) 
 end
```

I have the error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass". 
Do you know how to check if my token return an error ?

Comment: It means that `@token` is `nil`. In your controller, where does `@token` initially come from? If it is the result of `HTTParty.post(...)` you can of course not inspect it before fetching it. In that case, moveing the check below / after the `post` call should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes @token is the result of HTTParty.post(...). The thing is that I want to do the HTTParty.post only once the user land on my page, and not if he goes back to that page. If he goes back to this page, I have the error

Comment: In order to do so, you have to store the token somewhere else. Maybe in the user's session, i.e. via a cookie?

Comment: Yes, my token is stored in the LocalStorage. But can I access to the LocalStorage in Ruby ?

Comment: Unlike cookie data, the browser doesn't transfer local storage data to the server when requesting a page. So unless you explicitly send the data from the client side, the server isn't aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK in your view because you've assigned @token. Try:

```
if @token && @token['error']
```